# Django pagination get request going to dev server

Tags: javascript, python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am implementing pagination via an ajax call in Django.  I have everything working on my dev server, but when I move to my outward facing server to show the client, the get requests for the next page still route back to my localhost.

This is what I get in the javascript console:

```
"GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/uploadedwords/?page=2&title=indextest" 

This is what it should be:
"GET http://nameofmywebsite.com/uploadedwords/?page=2&title=indextest"
```

Is this a caching issue.  Is this because I still have debug mode on?  How does Django pagination decide what URL to send requests to?

Here is my views.py code.  I am using the Django Rest Framework:

```
def uploadedword_list(request):
    from mainsite.serializers import PaginatedUploadedWordSerializer

    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':

        submitted = SubmittedTextFile.objects.get(title=request.GET['title'])
        text = NlpParseText.objects.get(text=submitted)

        #words = UploadedWord.objects.filter(user=request.user, text=text)
        queryset = UploadedWord.objects.filter(user=request.user, text=text)
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, 500)

        page = request.GET['page']
        try:
            words = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            words = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999),
            # deliver last page of results.
            words = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = PaginatedUploadedWordSerializer(words,
                                                     context=serializer_context)
        #return Response(serializer.data)
        # serializer = UploadedWordSerializer(words, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = UploadedWordSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: "Django" doesn't do anything. You'll need to show the code that generates that link.

Comment: I have updated the post with the appropriate method from my views.  I should have included this in the first place..

Comment: You'll need to include the definition of ```PaginatedUploadedWordSerializer``` as well.